# Netsuite Rest API (beta) - filter by date time object

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to use Netsuite record API to find all customer payments between 2 dates.

This is working perfectly:

```
GET https://<account id>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customerpayment?q=tranDate ON_OR_AFTER "17/1/2023"
```

But any option to try passing a time, failed with the following error:

```
{
    "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Search error occurred: Parse of date/time \"17/1/2023 00:00\" failed with date format \"d/M/yy\" in time zone America/Los_Angeles\nCaused by:\n\tjava.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: \"17/1/2023 00:00\".",
            "o:errorQueryParam": "q",
            "o:errorCode": "INVALID_PARAMETER"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how I can solve this? I have no idea what I am doing wrong